# Laravel Filament Bulk action: how to set form and get values from there

Tags: laravel, forms, action, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I have a Filament Resource with a [Bulk Action](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/actions#bulk-actions) with modal confirm, and i have a form there to add some values for selected records. How i can access to the values of this form in `action` method?

```
<?php
$table->bulkActions([
    \Filament\Tables\Actions\BulkAction::make('my_action')
        ->requiresConfirmation()
        ->form(function (Collection $records) {
            \Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
        })
        ->action(function (Collection $records) {
            //i need a value of form TextInput [name] here
        });
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now i found the answer how to get form data/values from modal: via table `Livewire` object. Use `$table->getLivewire()->getMountedTableBulkActionForm()->getState()`.

Somewhere in your Filament Resource:

```
<?php
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\BulkAction;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->bulkActions([
            BulkAction::make('my_bulk_action')
                ->form(function (Collection $records) {
                    return [
                        TextInput::make('name')
                    ];
                })
                ->action(function (Collection $records) use ($table) {
                    $data = $table->getLivewire()->getMountedTableBulkActionForm()->getState();
                    // will return TextInput value in $data['name']
                });
        ]);
}
```

*Hope that helps.*